# Show the convergence of an integral

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

The question is asking to show the convergence and calculate the value of the integral $$ \int_0^{\infty} x^3 e^{-x} dx$$

I calculated the integral using the integral by parts 3 times and the result is 6. In the other hand, I don't have an idea how to show the convergence! any help?

Comment: Are you aware of estimates such as $x^n<e^{x/2}$ that hold for large enough $x$? The exact point from which onwards the inequality holds does depend on $n$, but the general theme of "exponential growth wins over polynomial growth" may ring a bell?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for the indication. In fact, no I am not aware about it!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that $\frac {x^{3}e^{-x}} {e^{-x/2}}$ is bounded and use the fact that $e^{-x/2}$ is integrable.

Comment: I understand how use the fact, but for the first part and how to show that the fraction is bounded no!

Comment: You can use L'Hopital's Rule to show that this continuous function tends to $0$ as $x\to \infty$ . Hence it is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

You need one of the standard estimates to justify the convergence. For the present task do the following (also standard, hence Community Wiki). Let $\sqrt{e}=1+a$. By the binomial formula we have for all integers $n\ge4$
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{n/2}&=(1+a)^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}\binom nk a^k\\
&>\binom n4a^4\\
&=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}a^4.
\end{aligned}
$$
Dividing this by $n^3$ gives the bound
$$
\frac{e^{n/2}}{n^3}>n(1-\frac1n)(1-\frac2n)(1-\frac3n)a^4\to \infty
$$
when $n\to\infty$. It follows that $x^3/e^{x/2}$ is bounded.